# Merging selected features in QGIS: some "borders" remain

Tags: qgis, merge

I'm trying to understand (and solve) the following issue in QGIS (2.16.3): I have a shapefile with hexagons which I want to merge. Doing so works, but certain "borders" (not sure about the correct term, sorry) inside the polygon remain, and I cannot figure out how to remove them (see below).

input:

[image]

output:

[image]

Comment: If you want to remove all polygon 'borders', you could try running the **Dissolve** tool on your layer.

Comment: thanks joseph - i've tried that but it leads to the same result.

Comment: May be you have geometry issues

Comment: Probably the vertices of adjacent polygons are not exactly the same and therefore the boundaries are not merged. You should snap the vertices with a reasonable tolerance as the first step.

Comment: thanks for your comments, which gave me some ideas. the vertices are ok, the problem was with the projection.

Answer (score 1):

ok, in the end there was some problem with the projection. i rerun the projection on the file and suddenly it worked.

thanks for your input and sorry for the bother, since the shapefile looked perfectly normal in qgis i never thought that the problem was there - or even that a faulty projection could prevent a proper merge.